# Pulling in data from an external system when creating an Orchard content item

Tags: orchardcms

I'm creating a module that defines a Product content part/type.  The content part includes properties that represent simple data elements, e.g. an item number, a unit price.  But it also includes more complex data - images, long and short (html) descriptions.

I've started down the road of using Orchard Fields for the complex data.  That way I get the editor benefits of the Text and MediaLibraryPicker fields.  I don't have to create those editor experiences in my editor template.

Much of the data that will be stored in this Orchard part already exists in another system, but the marketers who will be working in Orchard will want to change/supplement some of the data.  When adding a new Product content item in Orchard I'd like to prompt for the item number.  When the item number is filled in I'll make a call to a web service to pull the product information from the external database.  I'd like to then populate the fields on the New Product page with this information.  The marketer would then have the ability to edit/supplement the information pulled from the external database.

I'm just getting started with Orchard and am not sure of the best approach to accomplish this.  My initial thought was that the razor view should include an AJAX call to pull in the data.  Is that the best approach?  My view only includes some of the "fields", just the ones that are properties of my view model, not the ones that are defined as fields in my migration.  I suppose that shouldn't stop me, but it does seem odd that the javascript in the view would be referencing input elements that get added dynamically for the fields on my content part.

Is there another approach that I should consider?

**Edit**

Another approach I considered was having the New Product page only prompt for the item number.  The marketer could fill in just the item number field.  I could then populate most of the remaining fields with data from the external DB and the marketer could edit the item to change the values.  Maybe after adding the item, the page would redirect to the edit action.

I sort of like this approach.  It seems simpler to me because I'm more experienced with server-side than client-side development.  But I have no idea if this is even possible.

It probably doesn't matter, but I'm working with the latest Orchard bits (1.8 pre-release).

Comment: Very similar to a situation I am in at the moment... did you make any progress with this?

Comment: No.  I've punted temporarily since this user story hasn't made it to the top of our backlog yet.  For now, I created an Orchard command to import products from our source system and this has been good enough.

Comment: A bit late to the party here, but your second approach is absolutely possible and not that hard to implement either.

Comment: @MattVarblow What did you end up with?  External databases are a major concern for me and no system I've found, regardless of language, seems to cater to that market.

Comment: @johnny, we ended up creating a custom controller for the "New Product" page. We prompt for item number and use a custom controller action to pull the data from our external system, construct and save the content item as a draft, then redirect the user to the edit page for the new content item. The user can then edit and publish the product.